# PackageManager problems. How to fix?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a school project where you give voice commands.
the command if fairly simple, in the form of : "command" "parameter"
example: open facebook.I'm having a little bit of trouble with opening an app using just the app's name. It always crashes when i try and open another app with an Intent. I'll share below the code:

```
private boolean spokenTextContainsAnyOfTheCommands(List<String> commands) {
    for (int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++) {
        if (spokenText.contains(commands.get(i))) {
            currentCommand = commands.get(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
 private void handleCommand() {
    if (youSaidHello) {
        if (spokenTextContainsAnyOfTheCommands(callCommands)) {
            int idx = spokenText.indexOf(currentCommand);
            String whoToCall = spokenText.substring(idx + currentCommand.length()).trim();
            callThisDude(whoToCall);
        }

        if (spokenTextContainsAnyOfTheCommands(openCommands)) {
            int idx = spokenText.indexOf(currentCommand);
            String whatToOpen = spokenText.substring(idx + currentCommand.length()).trim();

            Intent appIntent = getAppIntent(whatToOpen);
            if (appIntent == null) {
                theTextView.setText(R.string.text_view_after_negative);
            }
            else {
                theTextView.setText(R.string.text_view_after_afirmative);
                startActivity(appIntent);
            }
        }


    }
    else {
        theTextView.setText(R.string.text_view_after_negative);
    }
}
private Intent getAppIntent(String appName) {
    String appPackage = null;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> appsInfo = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < appsInfo.size(); i++) {
        if (appsInfo.get(i).name.toLowerCase().equals(appName.toLowerCase())) {
            appPackage = appsInfo.get(i).packageName;
        }
    }

    if (appPackage == null) {
        theTextView.setText(R.string.text_view_after_negative);
    }
    else {
        theTextView.setText(R.string.text_view_after_afirmative);
    }
    return pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appPackage);

}
```

Do i need some kind of permission in the android manifest?

Answer (score 0):

```
String applicationName = (String) (appsInfo.get(i)!= null ? pm
 .getApplicationLabel(appsInfo.get(i)) : "(unknown)");
```

Found the problem. It was because of the way i got the name of the app. It's not appsInfo.get(i).name but the code above works.